# Driver for Realtek rtl8821ce (Lenovo 720S-13ARR ultrabook)

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, realtek, realtek-wireless

I built the required module for the 8821ce chip from source (https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce). 2.4GHz wifi is working fine, however 5GHz as well as bluetooth is not available.
Do I miss something or is it just not implemented completely by now?

Comment: Can I ask you which steps are needed to build the module? I downloaded the source files from github. Then tried run the make command but it complains and cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same module in HP Probook 440-G5 and have the same issue, for what I've found, it is not implemented yet :(. So we need to wait until someone implements them.

Comment: Please give a reference for this information

Comment: The only information driver that I could find but does not work on my laptop is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+bug/1742613. Note that this driver is for the bluetooth part only and is for the 8821CU Realtek module.

Answer (score 13):

Try that from your home directory

```
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce/
sudo make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a 8821ce
```

Comment: Well, if that works and the OP changes acceptance, ping me and I'll come back and upvote!

Comment: it now supports dkms - so no need to rebuild each time kernel is updated. see https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

Comment: works for a Idepad 320 (8821ce)

Comment: I confirm it worked well on my HP-da0001tx model. I tried many other similar git ways but faced different errors, like gcc error, kernel issues. But this method worked great. I believe there is some difference in git code in all those tried solutions. Thumbs up

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. +1