# Elan Touchpad not detected in ubuntu 18.04 and wifi adapter not found

Tags: wireless, touchpad

I am using Lenovo-ideapad 330-15ARR. I just install ubuntu 18.04. 
My touchpad(elan) is not detected and also under wifi menu in setting, "Wifi adapter not found" message is displayed.

My wifi network adapter is rtl8821ce .

I tried many solutions mentioned in various websites. But all was in vein.

And also I shall provide kernel versions and other outputs of some commands.

```
    santosh@santosh-Lenovo:~$ uname -r
    4.19.1-041901-lowlatency
```

My output for "xinput":

```
    santosh@santosh-Lenovo:~$ xinput
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My output for  "less /proc/bus/input/devices" :

```
    I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
    N: Name="Lid Switch"
    P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=event0 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=21
    B: SW=1

    I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
    N: Name="Power Button"
    P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=kbd event1 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=3
    B: KEY=10000000000000 0

    I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
    N: Name="Power Button"
    P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=kbd event2 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=3
    B: KEY=10000000000000 0

    I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
    N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
    P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=120013
    B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
    B: MSC=10
    B: LED=7

    I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
    N: Name="Video Bus"
    P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:03/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input4
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=kbd event4 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=3
    B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

    I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
    N: Name="Video Bus"
    P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0b/LNXVIDEO:02/input/input5
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=kbd event5 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=3
    B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

    I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
    N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
    P: Phys=ideapad/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input7
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event7 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=13
    B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
    B: MSC=10

    I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
    N: Name="HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
    P: Phys=ALSA
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.1/sound/card0/input8
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=event8 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=21
    B: SW=140

    I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
    N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Mic"
    P: Phys=ALSA
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1/input9
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=event9 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=21
    B: SW=10

    I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
    N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Headphone"
    P: Phys=ALSA
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1/input10
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=event10 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=21
    B: SW=4

    I: Bus=0003 Vendor=5986 Product=1127 Version=5307
    N: Name="EasyCamera: EasyCamera"    
    P: Phys=usb-0000:03:00.4-1/button
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input11
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=kbd event11 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=3
    B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

    I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1c4f Product=0003 Version=0110
    N: Name="SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse"
    P: Phys=usb-0000:03:00.3-4/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:1C4F:0003.0002/input/input12
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=17
    B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
    B: REL=103
    B: MSC=10
```

The output for "lspci" is

```
santosh@santosh-Lenovo:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d0
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d1
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15db
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15dc
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e8
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e9
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ea
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15eb
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ec
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ed
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ee
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ef
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega [Radeon Vega 8 Mobile] (rev c4)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15de
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15df
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e0
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e1
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e3
04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
```

please help me out with this problem.

I am also eager to know how to extract .inf file from .exe file , to install windows driver using ndiswrapper.

Comment: Edit the question to include results from terminal for `dmesg | grep -i elan`

Comment: Anyone answer this question please...

Comment: Go back to the 4.15 kernels and use https://askubuntu.com/a/1046580/300665 to fix wifi.  If you want touchpad to work, post the info I request

Answer (score 0):

## Lenovo ideapad 330 (15ARR) ubuntu issues and their solutions

### Issue-1: None of the ubuntu distros are getting installed

**Solution**: Ubuntu distros lower than `18.10` will not work in this laptop, as minimum kernal version required is `4.18`.

So install ubuntu 18.10 / xubuntu 18.10 / lubuntu 18.10 / kubuntu 18.10 in `UEFI` mode

### Issue-2: Wifi is not working

**Solution**: Install drivers seperatly. In most of the cases the wifi network card manufacturer is `Elan tech` for this model.

So just run the following commands to download and install

```
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce/
sudo make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a 8821ce
```

Check your wifi networks!

### Issue-3: Touchpad is not working at all

**Solution**: You need to upgrade kernel to minimum `4.19.15-041915-generic`
. From these kernal version, the touchpad drivers are present in the kernal.

So just download the kernal files and upgrade.
Visit https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ to choose a kernal version

If you want to download `4.19.15`, try the steps

First download the files

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.15/linux-headers-4.19.15-041915_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.15/linux-headers-4.19.15-041915-generic_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.15/linux-modules-4.19.15-041915-generic_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.15/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.15-041915-generic_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_amd64.deb
```

Install

```
dpkg -i linux-headers-4.19.15-041915_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_all.deb
dpkg -i linux-headers-4.19.15-041915-generic_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-modules-4.19.15-041915-generic_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-image-unsigned-4.19.15-041915-generic_4.19.15-041915.201901130432_amd64.deb
```

Reboot